# How to shorten nested namespaces in a return type which is private to an inner class?

Tags: c++, namespaces, private-members

This question is about dealing with a long nested private class namespace in a method return type in `.cpp` files.
There have been [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827985/can-i-avoid-using-the-class-name-in-the-cpp-file-if-i-declare-a-namespace-in-th) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065563/c-class-namespaces) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887211/is-it-possible-to-avoid-repeating-the-class-name-in-the-implementation-file) avoiding long names and nested namespaces in a `cpp` file, but they don't seem to cover my use case.

I have a private [nested class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) with a private type specific to that class in a header `.h` file, something like this:

```
class outer {
    class inner {
        typedef map<int, map<int, int>> footype;
    private:
        footype manipulate_foos(footype f1, footype f2);
    }
}
```

Defining a method in the `.cpp` file, the compiler complains if I do not use the full path of namespaces to the return type, even though the namespace is inferred in the argument types. So I have to write something like

```
outer::inner::footype outer::inner::manipulate_foos(footype f1, footypte f2) {
    // body
}
```

which in my case requires splitting the return type and method name on multiple lines, and is painfully unreadable.

### Question

**Is there any way to omit the namespaces in the return type when that type is private to an inner class?**

---

### Notes

- To be clear, I do not want to omit the namespaces in the method name; I understand the value of these and I feel they do not hinder readability, while the namespaces in the return type are hurting readability. Since this is a private method, I don't think it helps to have the full return type spelled out.
- So far I tried the following solution in the `.cpp` file:

  ```
  using footype = outer::inner::footype
  ```

  but it gives me the error `'class outer::inner::footype' is private within this context.`

Comment: I haven't posted a lot of questions on SO (although I'm active on other SEs) so would really appreciate any help in how to improve the question. If you can comment, much appreciated!! Also, I couldn't find a duplicate, but let me know if I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
auto outer::inner::manipulate_foos(footype f1, footype f2) -> footype { ... }
```

Comment: Nice solution! It works indeed, and this may be a compelling use case for trailing return types.